# Error in PhoneGap, Visual Project 2010: The command CScript exited with code 1

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-7, cordova

I'm trying to make an application for windows phone 7 with the framework phonegap, in Visual Studio 2010. But I get an error when I'm trying to compile the project. The error is:

> Error 1
>   The command "CScript "C:\Users\Alan\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\PhoneGapStarter\PhoneGapStarter\BuildManifestProcessor.js" "C:\Users\Alan\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\PhoneGapStarter\PhoneGapStarter\PhoneGapStarter.csproj"" exited with code 1. PhoneGapStarter

I'm using the *phonegap library 1.6.1 (cordova)*, but I can't see what the problem is. 
I tried to download the library again and added it to the project, but that didn't help.

What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and it was because the environmental variable for CScript wasn't set up.

I fixed it by referencing the cscript.exe directly. You can do this by opening the csproj file in a text editor and changing this line

```
<PreBuildEvent>CScript "$(ProjectDir)/ManifestProcessor.js" "$(ProjectPath)"</PreBuildEvent>
```

to

```
<PreBuildEvent>C:\windows\system32\cscript.exe "$(ProjectDir)/ManifestProcessor.js" "$(ProjectPath)"</PreBuildEvent>
```

or you can add a new environmental variable

Answer (score 2):

Try to find CordovaSourceDictionary.xml and check if it is read-only. If so, make it writable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes in effect, that was the problem, the error was the enviroment of windows for the js scripts.

So, the solution for this problem was the next:

1. As administrator, run the next script in the comand line (cmd).
   --> `regsvr32 %systemroot%\system32\jscript.dll`
2. Once to the script was run, download the following file [(vista_js_fix.reg)](http://www.winhelponline.com/downloadattachment.php?aId=2c4993275fa7c5b7a1e243a62867858a&articleId=230%22%20%27=%22vista_js_fix.reg%22) and run as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue because `.js` files were associated with another app, which was PhpStorm in my case, but could be any other in your case, e.g Notepad++

Sorted out by running following in the command prompt (as Administrator):

```
regsvr32 %systemroot%\system32\jscript.dll

assoc .js=JSFile
```