# TFS: Having Trouble Getting a Phonegap solution from TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cordova, tfs

I am having trouble distributing my Phonegap solution from TFS.

The thing is the project works fine when I created the solution ***(builds an runs successfully)*** and was able to upload it to TFS successfully, but when other developers gets the solution it always returns an error when building.

This is the error my co-developers are receiving

[image: This is the error that my co-develoeprs are receiving]

I am using:

1. Phonegap 2.4.0
2. Windows Phone 7.8 SDK
3. Visual Studio 2010

Comment: try cleaning twice, and then rebuild?

Comment: what is the permission denied error? have you checked to see if you have checked in a compile time file that would then show up in all your colleagues workspace as readonly?

Comment: I got the same problem Drew, have you since resolved the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10310718/606602), find CordovaSourceDictionary.xml in the project folder and check if it is read-only. If so, make it writable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can't believe it was that simple! :)

Unfortunately this project of ours was cancelled. so I did not try to research into it more.